# How to access static class member from an interface

Tags: typescript

First of all, I am new in `TypeScript` and this question might be simple for you :/.

I've a car `class` that has a static member variable, a number, named 
`NUMBER_OF_WHEELS`. I've an `interface` also named `CarProps` that has `wheels` property which can be either a number or `NUMBER_OF_WHEELS`.

```
interface CarProps {
    wheels: number[] | Car.NUMBER_OF_WHEELS
}

class Car {
    public static readonly NUMBER_OF_WHEELS = 4;
}
```

but when I try to access `NUMBER_OF_WHEELS` from `CarProps`. I am getting

`TS2702: 'Car' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.`

- Is it possible to use the static member of a class inside an
  interface ?
- Is this the right method to do it ?
- How can I fix this ?

[image]

Comment: What you put after the colon (`:`) is the type of the variable. The type is number. Not NUMBER_OF_WHEELS. NUMBER_OF_WHEELS is a value, not a type. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the number to be either a `number` or value inside the `NUMBER_OF_WHEELS` variable. Is this not the right way to do it ?

Comment: Well, the value inside the NUMBER_OF_WHEELS is 4, so you want wheels to be either a number, or 4, which is a number. So you want wheels to be a number.

Comment: Ok. change of code `wheels: number[] | Car.NUMBER_OF_WHEELS`, How about now ?

Comment: What if i want the `wheels` to either a `number` array or number inside the `NUMBER_OF_WHEELS`. How can i accomplish this condition ?

Comment: Please edit your question then. AFAIK, you can't. You can use number[] | 4, though.

Comment: Question edited. but `wheels: number[] | 4` shows no error. If that's possible `wheels: number[] | Car.NUMBER_OF_WHEELS` should be working, right ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173577/discussion-between-theapache64-and-jb-nizet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Typescript!

Typescript provides annotations on top of javascript to describe the types of the data in a program. It does its work during the compile step, before any code runs. The reason you can't "access" a static property of a class and use it as a type is that static properties (even very readonly ones) are still part of the runtime value of the class.

What you need is a type! Try this:

```
type NUMBER_OF_WHEELS = 4 // this is a type, the type is '4'

interface CarProps {
    wheels: number[] | NUMBER_OF_WHEELS
}

class Car {
    // the type of this variable is '4' so it can ONLY be assigned the value 4
    public static readonly NUMBER_OF_WHEELS: NUMBER_OF_WHEELS = 4;
}
```

This is the answer: typescript happens *before* any variables are assigned any values. So typescript *can't* inspect values of variables. On the other hand, because typescript happens before any variables are assigned any values, you can use typescript to narrow the possible values that can be assigned to variables.

Types come first.

---

Finally: when posting a question on stack overflow, you will get a more helpful answer if you post real code. This question, as posed, seems like it is just a misconception about when compile time is. If you post the real code you are working on, then someone might be able to suggest a different approach to the problem and help lead you to some more satisfying answer.

Comment: I got it. :) Thank you for your time and effort.